# In heaven, will we have desires (Catholic)?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, thomas-aquinas

St. Thomas Aquinas once wrote that in heaven, our desires will be completely at rest. This sounds to me that we will not have any desire in heaven, as there is nothing to desire for. But at the same time he also said that we will continue to seek God in heaven, which seems to imply that we will "desire" God in heaven (also there could be many other things in heaven that will make us to have "desire").

Will we have desires in heaven (please answer according to Catholic understanding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catholic theology speaks of [***The Satiety of the Blessed***](http://www.catholictreasury.info/books/everlasting_life/ev32.php#bk1) in the following manner:

> **This state of satiety is always new and never passes away.** St. Augustine writes: "All our life will be one Amen, one Alleluia. Sadden
>   not yourselves by considering this truth in a carnal manner, as if in
>   heaven, just as on earth, we could become weary by repeating the
>   words: Amen, Alleluia. This heavenly Amen, this Alleluia, will not be
>   expressed by sound which passes away, but by the emotions of love, the
>   emotions of the soul embraced by love. "Amen" means "It is true."
>   "Alleluia" means "praise God." God is the immovable truth, who knows
>   neither defect nor progress, neither decline nor growth. He is truth,
>   eternal and stable: truth forever incorruptible.
>
> **"We shall sing our Amen forever but with a satiety that is insatiable. With satiety, because we live in perfect abundance, but
>   with an insatiable satiety, because this good, while it satisfies
>   completely, produces also a pleasure ever new.** Insatiably satiated
>   by this truth, we shall repeat forever: Amen. Rest and gaze: that is
>   our eternal Sabbath."

And [St. Josemaría Escrivá](http://www.josemariaescriva.info/section/saint_josemaria) writes:

> Think how pleasing to God Our Lord is the incense burnt in his honour.
>   Think also how little the things of this earth are worth; even as they
>   begin they are already ending. In Heaven, instead, a great Love awaits
>   you, with no betrayals and no deceptions. The fullness of love, the
>   fullness of beauty and greatness and knowledge... And it will never
>   cloy: **it will satiate, yet still you will want more.** - [*The Forge,
>   995*](http://www.escrivaworks.org/book/the_forge-point-995.htm).

Therefore Catholic theology speaks of the satiety of the blessed in heaven that is always new, never passes away, is full and complete, yet still wants more i.e., it is *an insatiable satiety*.

Comment: does the church provide any explanations on why we will still desire more in heaven despite experiencing such satiety?

Comment: Also in heaven, is it possible for us to desire things that is not "directly related to God"?

Comment: @jdschnieder 1) Follows from an infinite God filling a finite vessel. 2) *[T]he new heaven and the new earth will afford [the Blessed] manifold enjoyment.*- Cf. [Heaven | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07170a.htm).

Comment: @Domenico *Is it possible for us to desire things that is not "directly related to God"?* About the woman who had 7 husbands, Jesus said : "For in the resurrection they shall neither marry nor be married; but shall be as the angels of God in heaven" (Matthew 22:30 D-R). Then you have the answer for the desire of a woman or a man. As our bodies will not be as our earthly ones - we will be as angels -, it is more likely that we will not have desires of things like drinking, eating, etc.